# How can I enable lsp-headerline-breadcrumb-mode in lsp-mode?

Tags: lsp-mode

I would like to enable lsp-headerline-breadcrumb-mode in every buffer where lsp-mode is active.

I'd know how to do it for every mode, for example

```
(use-package go-mode
  :ensure t
  :config
  (add-hook 'go-mode-hook (lambda ()
                            ;; other stuff
                            (lsp-headerline-breadcrumb-mode t)
                            )
            )
  )
```

But I fail to do it for every buffer with `lsp-mode` ...
With this, lsp-mode doesn't work at all:

```
(use-package lsp-mode
  :ensure t
  :commands (lsp lsp-deferred)
  :hook
  (go-mode . lsp-deferred)
  (python-mode . (lambda ()
                   (require 'lsp-python-ms)
                   (lsp-deferred)))
  :config (setq
           lsp-diagnostic-package :auto
           ;; stuff deleted
           lsp-print-performance nil
           )
  (add-hook 'lsp-mode-hook (lambda ()
                            ((lsp-headerline-breadcrumb-mode t))
                            )
            )
  )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a variable you can customize that automatically enables the headerline breadcrumb mode whenever `lsp-mode` is active. Try something like:

```
(use-package lsp-mode
  :custom
  (lsp-headerline-breadcrumb-enable t))
```

Answer (score 1):

The following snippet works for me, it enables breadcrumbs in all modes where `lsp` is active.

```
(require 'package)
(setq package-user-dir (expand-file-name "~/.emacs.d/elpa/")
      package-enable-at-startup nil)
(add-to-list 'package-archives
             '("melpa" . "https://melpa.org/packages/") t)
(package-initialize)

(unless (package-installed-p 'use-package)
  (package-refresh-contents)
  (package-install 'use-package))
(eval-when-compile
  (require 'use-package))

(add-hook 'c++-mode-hook #'lsp)
(add-hook 'python-mode-hook #'lsp)

(use-package lsp-mode
  :ensure t
  :commands (lsp lsp-deferred)
  :hook ((lsp-mode . lsp-enable-which-key-integration)
         (lsp-managed-mode . lsp-modeline-diagnostics-mode)
         (lsp-mode . lsp-headerline-breadcrumb-mode)
         (lsp-mode . lsp-modeline-code-actions-mode)))
```

Here I have only included `c++-mode` and `python-mode`. I usually prefer to enable `lsp` from the corresponding major mode `use-package` declarations.